# nfs client on ubuntu 9.10, /etc/init.d/nfs-common does not exist

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, nfsclient

This seems like a trivial problem, but I can not find a solution for several days now.

I am trying to configure an nfs client on ubuntu 9.10 (64 bit).  All the tutorials I've read say I need to restart a few things, such as portmap, and also nfs-common.  Specifically:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-common restart
```

However, this file (/etc/init.d/nfs-common) does not exist.

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

returns 
    "nfs-common is already the newest version."

When I try:

```
sudo service nfs restart
```

I get:

```
nfs: unrecognized service
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you to the kind soul who can help me with this.

Comment: I found this explanation: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+question/85669
Still unclear about what is needed to initialize the nfs client now that /etc/init.d/nfs-common has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

OK - well.  Things are working for me now.  Here's what I did.  I installed a fresh version Ubuntu and ran:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

Whatever client processes are needed started up just fine, and I am able to run mount without issue.

Here's the output:

dlumma@d-linux64-22:~$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common
[sudo] password for dlumma: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-2.6.31-14 linux-headers-2.6.31-14-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgssglue1 libnfsidmap2 librpcsecgss3 portmap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgssglue1 libnfsidmap2 librpcsecgss3 nfs-common portmap
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 356kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,188kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main libgssglue1 0.1-3 [24.2kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main libnfsidmap2 0.21-2 [31.0kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main librpcsecgss3 0.18-1 [35.8kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main portmap 6.0-10ubuntu2 [37.8kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main nfs-common 1:1.2.0-2ubuntu8 [227kB]
Fetched 356kB in 2s (141kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgssglue1.
(Reading database ... 138745 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libgssglue1 (from .../libgssglue1_0.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libnfsidmap2.
Unpacking libnfsidmap2 (from .../libnfsidmap2_0.21-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package librpcsecgss3.
Unpacking librpcsecgss3 (from .../librpcsecgss3_0.18-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package portmap.
Unpacking portmap (from .../portmap_6.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package nfs-common.
Unpacking nfs-common (from .../nfs-common_1%3a1.2.0-2ubuntu8_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libgssglue1 (0.1-3) ...

Setting up libnfsidmap2 (0.21-2) ...

Setting up librpcsecgss3 (0.18-1) ...

Setting up portmap (6.0-10ubuntu2) ...
portmap start/running, process 2122

Setting up nfs-common (1:1.2.0-2ubuntu8) ...

Creating config file /etc/idmapd.conf with new version

Creating config file /etc/default/nfs-common with new version
Adding system user `statd' (UID 113) ...
Adding new user`statd' (UID 113) with group `nogroup' ...
Not creating home directory`/var/lib/nfs'.
statd start/running, process 2343
gssd stop/waiting
idmapd stop/pre-start, process 2396

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place